# Merge is not returning right data

Tags: oracle

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
employee_id NUMBER(5),
first_name  VARCHAR2(20),
last_name   VARCHAR2(20),
dept_no     NUMBER(2),
salary      NUMBER(10));
```

Table employee has values:

```
(1, 'Dan', 'Morgan', 10, 100000);
(2, 'Helen', 'Lofstrom', 20, 100000);
(3, 'Akiko', 'Toyota', 20, 50000);
(4, 'Jackie', 'Stough', 20, 40000);
(5, 'Richard', 'Foote', 20, 70000);
(6, 'Joe', 'Johnson', 20, 30000);
(7, 'Clark', 'Urling', 20, 90000);

CREATE TABLE bonuses (
employee_id NUMBER, bonus NUMBER DEFAULT 100);
```

Table bonuses has values:

```
(1,100);
(2,100);
(4,100);
(6,100);
(7,100);
```

And I did merge based on bonuses table:

```
MERGE INTO bonuses b
USING (
  SELECT employee_id, salary, dept_no
  FROM employee
  WHERE dept_no =20) e
ON (b.employee_id = e.employee_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE  SET b.bonus = e.salary * 0.1
  DELETE WHERE (e.salary < 40000)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT  (b.employee_id, b.bonus)
  VALUES (e.employee_id, e.salary * 0.05)
  WHERE (e.salary > 40000);
```

And when I 
    select * from bonuses;

```
EMPLOYEE_ID BONUS 
------------------
1           100   
2           10000 
3           2500  
4           4000  
5           3500  
7           9000
```

My question is "where is my bonuses record for employee_id #6"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted by `DELETE WHERE (e.salary < 40000)` statement?.
And You should probably make one of you conditions to include equality.
After all someone salary may be just 40K just like Jackie's.